# Using SPO & Teams for a department - Check my work!

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, microsoft-teams

I have a department whom I have made an O365 Group for.  Now they have a SPO Site, Teams, OneNote, etc.

I made the SPO Site a Hub site, and this is the part where I just want to clarify before I go make a bunch of changes:

The department, has 6 sub-departments.  I was planning on making 6 site collections, and joining them to the original hubsite.   There will be overlapping people in these sub-departments.

I think for permissions, it will make life easier this way as I will be able to delegate the file libraries access a lot easier.

The question is for Teams.  Will using MS Teams facilitate this correctly?  Is there a way to associate channels with the document libraries that are made?  I imagine if I make the site collections and join them, those files will not be part of Teams since permissions will be all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Teams channels associate their own SharePoint library folder. AFAIK you cannot point a Teams channel to another site. You could, however, set up a tab and link it to the other SharePoint site.

If the six department sites are also linked to O365 groups, then you can have corresponding six Teams spaces that can point to these existing sites and the Channels point to the Documents library.

If your issue is with document access, then you may not want to use Teams for files at all. Everybody in a Teams space has access to all stuff in Teams. It is not intended for complicated permissions. That defeats the purpose of Teams.

Comment: Well I hear you on the last part.  I think using the channels and then just adding a site as a tab to that particular document library may be good enough.  The entire department would still utilize the main "Teams" file access.  I think simply making them site collections and adding them to the hub should be good enough permission wise.